# How do I obtain CPU cycle count in Win32?

Tags: winapi, timer, cpu-cycles

In Win32, is there any way to get a unique cpu cycle count or something similar that would be uniform for multiple processes/languages/systems/etc.

I'm creating some log files, but have to produce multiple logfiles because we're hosting the .NET runtime, and I'd like to avoid calling from one to the other to log. As such, I was thinking I'd just produce two files, combine them, and then sort them, to get a coherent timeline involving cross-world calls.

However, GetTickCount does not increase for every call, so that's not reliable. Is there a better number, so that I get the calls in the right order when sorting?

---

**Edit**: Thanks to [@Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) that put me on the track to QueryPerformanceCounter, which did the trick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [RDTSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDTSC) CPU instruction (assuming x86). This instruction gives the CPU cycle counter, but be aware that it will increase very quickly to its maximum value, and then reset to 0. As the Wikipedia article mentions, you might be better off using the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904.aspx) function.

Answer (score 12):

[Heres an interesting article!](http://www.geisswerks.com/ryan/FAQS/timing.html) says not to use RDTSC, but to instead use [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904).

Conclusion:

> Using regular old `timeGetTime()` to do
>   timing is not reliable on many
>   Windows-based  operating systems
>   because the granularity of the system
>   timer can be as high as 10-15 
>   milliseconds, meaning that
>   `timeGetTime()` is only accurate to
>   10-15 milliseconds. [Note that the
>   high granularities occur on NT-based
>   operation systems like Windows NT,
>   2000, and XP.  Windows 95 and 98 tend
>   to have much better granularity,
>   around 1-5 ms.]
>
> However, if you call
>   `timeBeginPeriod(1)` at the beginning of
>   your program (and  `timeEndPeriod(1)` at
>   the end), `timeGetTime()` will usually
>   become accurate to 1-2  milliseconds,
>   and will provide you with extremely
>   accurate timing information.
>
> `Sleep()` behaves similarly; the length
>   of time that `Sleep()` actually sleeps
>   for  goes hand-in-hand with the
>   granularity of `timeGetTime()`, so after
>   calling  `timeBeginPeriod(1)` once,
>   `Sleep(1)` will actually sleep for 1-2
>   milliseconds,`Sleep(2)` for 2-3, and so
>   on (instead of sleeping in increments
>   as high as 10-15 ms).
>
> **For higher precision timing
>   (sub-millisecond accuracy), you'll
>   probably want to avoid  using the
>   assembly mnemonic RDTSC because it is
>   hard to calibrate**; instead, use 
>   `QueryPerformanceFrequency` and
>   `QueryPerformanceCounter`, which are
>   accurate to less  than 10 microseconds
>   (0.00001 seconds).
>
> For simple timing, both timeGetTime
>   and QueryPerformanceCounter work well,
>   and  QueryPerformanceCounter is
>   obviously more accurate.  However, if
>   you need to do  any kind of "timed
>   pauses" (such as those necessary for
>   framerate limiting), you  need to be
>   careful of sitting in a loop calling
>   QueryPerformanceCounter, waiting  for
>   it to reach a certain value; this will
>   eat up 100% of your processor. 
>   Instead,  consider a hybrid scheme,
>   where you call Sleep(1) (don't forget
>   timeBeginPeriod(1)  first!) whenever
>   you need to pass more than 1 ms of
>   time, and then only enter the 
>   QueryPerformanceCounter 100%-busy loop
>   to finish off the last < 1/1000th of a
>   second of the delay you need.  This
>   will give you ultra-accurate delays
>   (accurate  to 10 microseconds), with
>   very minimal CPU usage.  See the code
>   above.

Comment: Please avoid timeBeginPeriod(); it affects the system-wide scheduler and may cause problems with energy saving.

Answer (score 2):

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() return the number of CPU cycle since a time origin (maybe when the computer start, but I'm not sure) and I've never seen it not increased between 2 calls.

The CPU Cycles will be specific for each computer so you can't use it to merge log file between 2 computers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm only going to merge files produced on the same computer in the same timeframe, so that would work. Now I just need to find out what that method actually calls :)

Answer (score 2):

RDTSC output may depend on the current core's clock frequency, which for modern CPUs is neither constant nor, in a multicore machine, consistent.

Use the system time, and if dealing with feeds from multiple systems use an NTP time source. You can get reliable, consistent time readings that way; if the overhead is too much for your purposes, using the [HPET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HPET) to work out time elapsed since the last known reliable time reading is better than using the HPET alone.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GetTickCount and add another counter as you merge the log files.  Won't give you perfect sequence between the different log files, but it will at least keep all logs from each file in the correct order.

Comment: The tick count seems to increase coinciding with the millisecond output, and that's why I need something slightly more accurate.