# Data type size impact on performance

Tags: c++, performance, types

I'm running intensive numerical simulations. I often use long integers, but I realized it would be safe to use integers instead. Would this improve the speed of my simulations significantly?

Comment: It depends.  It depends on the processor, if you're running it on the GPU or CPu.  It depends on how much memory you're consuming versus the amount of virtual memory you need to allocate.  It depends on... you get the idea?  Give us more information.

Comment: Are you sure that sizeof(long int) != sizeof(int) on your platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends. If you have lots and lots of numbers consecutively in memory, they're more likely to fit in the L2 cache, so you have fewer cache misses. L2 cache misses - depending on your platform - can be a significant performance impact, so it's definitely a good idea to make things fit in cache as much as possible (and prefetch if you can). But don't expect your code to fly all of a sudden because your types are smaller.

EDIT: One more thing - if you choose an awkward type (like a 16-bit integer on a 32-bit or 64-bit platform), you may end up with worse performance because the CPU will have to surgically extract the 16-bit value and turn it into something it can work with. But typically, ints are a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your data set sizes. Obviously, halving the size of your integers could double the amount of data that fits into CPU caches and thus access to data would be faster. For more details I suggest you read the famous Ulrich Drepper's paper [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

All the answers have already treated the CPU cache issue: if your data is two times smaller, then in some cases it can fit into L2 cache completely, yielding performance boost.

However, there is another very important and more general thing: memory bandwidth. If you algorithm is linear (aka *O(N)* complexity) and accesses memory sequentally, then it may be memory-bound. It means that memory reads/writes are the bottleneck, and CPU is simply wasting a lot of cycles waiting for memory operations to complete. In such case reducing total memory size in two times would yield reliable 2x performance boost.
Moreover, in such cases switching to bytes may yield even more performance boost, despite the fact that CPU computations may be slower with bytes as one of the other answerers have already mentioned.

In general, the answer depends on several things like: total size of data your algorithm works with, memory access pattern (random/sequental), algorithm asymptotic complexity, computation per memory ratio (mostly for linear algorithms).

Answer (score -1):

This is why typedef is your friend. :-)

If mathematically possible, try using floats instead of integers. I read somewhere that floating point arithmetic (esp. multiplication) can actually be faster on some processors.

The best thing is to experiment and benchmark. It's damn near impossible to figure out analytically which micro-optimizations work best.

EDIT: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550281/floating-point-vs-integer-calculations-on-modern-hardware) discusses the performance difference between integer and float.