# Float and int data types affects performance

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, algorithm, data-structures

I am doing research on data types and I started with INT and Float. I did a simple loop that has an equation inside it. The loop is first executed with int data  type and then with float . The code is done in objective c but the idea is that they take the same time. However, while checking the instruments tool in the xcode, it seems that the float run more cycles on the CPU.
Can anybody explain please?

Comment: What is your target? x86, ARM, something else? If your target doesn't support float natively, you might be using soft floats (which are very slow).

Comment: i am using xcode for iphone ARM

Comment: Can you post your code? Amongst other things, there could be some compiler optimizations that are taking place (such as throwing away the result if it's not used), etc..

Comment: thanks hexist the code is only for loop and simple equation it it for (int i=0,i<n,i++) { x = i + (9000 * 8 ) / 2 }

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550281/floating-point-vs-integer-calculations-on-modern-hardware

Comment: @user1760556 Any competent compiler will reduce that to x = i + 36000, and as n doesn't change inside the loop, an optimizing compiler could eleiminate the loop as well and just evaluate the final value of x at compile time. The test proves nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Floating-point arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Floating-point_arithmetic_operations) is by far more complicated than integer arithmetics. Usually, CPUs even have a dedicated [FPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) circuitry to perform floating-point operations. Thus, what you have observed is to be expected.