# Why thread having int variable calculation is faster than thread having double variable?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I had prepared two sample code for showing thread having int variable calculation is faster than thread having double variable.

Only difference between two code is, in first i am using only integers and in other i am using only double.

**Time difference between them is almost 30%.**

Reason might be very simple/basic, but can anyone please give me the possible reason(s)?

Note: please ignore the logic of the code, because it is just prepared for demo.

Using integer :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

    pthread_t pth1,pth2,pth3,pth4;

    void *threadfunc1(void *parm)
    {
        int i,j,k,l;
        j = 0;
        k = 0;
        l = 5;
        for (i = 0; i < 5000000; i ++) {
            j = k + 152;
            k = j + 21;
            l = j + k + (j * 5) + (k * 2) + (l * 3);
            j = k + ((l + j)/ k) + j + k + (l / k);
            j = 0;
            k = 0;
            l = 5;
        }
        printf("Completed Thread 1\n");
        return NULL ;
    }
    void *threadfunc2(void *parm)
    {
        int i,j,k,l;
        j = 0;
        k = 0;
        l = 5;
        for (i = 0; i < 5000000; i ++) {
            j = k + 152;
            k = j + 21;
            l = j + k + (j * 5) + (k * 2) + (l * 3);
            j = k + ((l + j)/ k) + j + k + (l / k);
            j = 0;
            k = 0;
            l = 5;
        }
        printf("Completed Thread 2\n");
        return NULL ;
    }


    int main () {
        pthread_create(&pth1, NULL, threadfunc1, "foo");
        pthread_create(&pth2, NULL, threadfunc2, "foo");
        pthread_join( pth1, NULL);
        pthread_join( pth2, NULL);
        return 1;
    }
```

Using double:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

    pthread_t pth1,pth2,pth3,pth4;

    void *threadfunc1(void *parm)
    {
        double i,j,k,l;
        j = 0;
        k = 0;
        l = 5;
        for (i = 0; i < 5000000; i ++) {
            j = k + 152;
            k = j + 21;
            l = j + k + (j * 5) + (k * 2) + (l * 3);
            j = k + ((l + j)/ k) + j + k + (l / k);
            j = 0;
            k = 0;
            l = 5;
        }
        printf("Completed Thread 1\n");
        return NULL ;
    }
    void *threadfunc2(void *parm)
    {
        double i,j,k,l;
        j = 0;
        k = 0;
        l = 5;
        for (i = 0; i < 5000000; i ++) {
            j = k + 152;
            k = j + 21;
            l = j + k + (j * 5) + (k * 2) + (l * 3);
            j = k + ((l + j)/ k) + j + k + (l / k);
            j = 0;
            k = 0;
            l = 5;
        }
        printf("Completed Thread 2\n");
        return NULL ;
    }


    int main () {
        pthread_create(&pth1, NULL, threadfunc1, "foo");
        pthread_create(&pth2, NULL, threadfunc2, "foo");
        pthread_join( pth1, NULL);
        pthread_join( pth2, NULL);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with threads. Floating-point operations are simply much slower than integral operations.

Comment: ok. I was wondering it is in the case of threads only. Let me get the benchmark for simple code without thread. thanks @JonathonReinhart

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550281/floating-point-vs-integer-calculations-on-modern-hardware

Comment: yes got that @JonathonReinhart and @ jeyaram found the difference in benchmark with simple code also. thanks

Comment: Aside from any inherent performance differences between integer and floating point operations, you're comparing apples and oranges -- the two programs do not compute the same thing.

Comment: @R.. please elaborate more on "the two programs do not compute the same thing." I would like to learn more on this statement.

Comment: Unless `l + j` is a[n integer] multiple of `k`, the expression `(l + j)/ k` has completely different meaning when the types of `l`, `j`, and `k` are floating point types as opposed to integer types.

Comment: hmmm.. right.. removing j = k + ((l + j)/ k) + j + k + (l / k); from all threads changed the time difference between both code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This difference is because of usage of floating point. For example, have a look at the following simple program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  TYPE i,s=0;

  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    s += i;
  }

  printf("Sum=%d\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `gcc -o main main.c` and have a look on its `main()` function disassembly for `TYPE` defined as `fixed` (left) and `double` (right):
[image: fixed vs float, no optimization]
Arrows show `for(){}` loop from main. Target is X86 processor.

For `gcc -O3 -o main main.c` fixed point still wins:
[image]

Thus fixed point is more preferable for high speed computations if algorithm allows its usage. And this situation remains almost the same if double is replaced with a float.

Moreover some processors have no floating point at all and use special optimized emulation libraries (for instance - [TI C64x+ family](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=spru732&fileType=pdf)). In that case difference between performance of fixed and floating point will ~10x.

Comment: Why do you have to use legacy target?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I meant that I used x86 compatible processor, not exactly 8086 or similar processor. You think it will be better to correct it?

Comment: The stack based FP processor is probably slower (having 80 bit internal precision) than its xmm based counterpart.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Undoubtedly, `SSE` can be advantageous, but does compiler itself can add it to program code? I think [instrinsics](http://www.cs.uaf.edu/2009/fall/cs301/lecture/11_13_sse_intrinsics.html) should be used to do that. In addition it is not very comfortable to use it in a loops like in the question.

Comment: My gcc 4.6.3 on x64 produces SSE instructions by default.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen My gcc-4.8.1 needs flag -mfpmath=sse and -march=corei7  to start generate them. By default - no SSE (Ubuntu 13.10/32bits). You're right - it becomes little faster: 0m3.246s(no SSE) vs 0m2.981s(SSE). But fixed point still wins: 0m2.599s.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point arithmetic operations take more CPU cycles than integers, the HW is much (much much) more complex.

This has nothing to do with threads.

Also most processors have more parallel execution resources for integers than they have for floating point as integer operations are used more than floating point in general.