# converting integers to minutes

Tags: c, time

I am new to C programming, but experienced in Java. I am creating a simple console application to calculate time between two chosen values. I am storing the chosen values in an int array like this:

```
static int timeVals[] = {748,800,815,830,845,914,929,942,953,1001,1010,1026,1034,1042,1048};
```

I am calling a method diff to calculate the time between to values liek this:

```
int diff (int start, int slut) {
/* slut means end in danish. not using rude words, but I am danish */
int minutes = 0;
int time = 0;
double hest;
hest = (100/60);
printf("hest = %f", hest);
if(timeVals[start] > timeVals[slut])
{
    minutes = timeVals[start] - timeVals[slut];
    /* printing hest to see what the value is */
    printf("t = %f",hest);
    time = minutes * (100/60);
    printf("minut diff: %d\n", time);
}
else
{
    minutes = timeVals[slut] - timeVals[start];
    tiem = time + (minutes * (100/60));
}

return time;
}
```

The weird thing is that when I print out `hest` value I get 1.000000, which I mean isn't right... I have been struggling with this for hours now, and I can't find the issue.. maybe I'm just bad at math :P

hope you can help me

Comment: `100/60` divides two integers. use `100.0 / 60.0` instead.

Comment: Minor issue: last line of the else clause ... should be time = not tiem =

Comment: @ajay "slut" in swedish is equal to end ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is

`hest = (100/60)`

This result will be 1 because 100 / 60 = 1.6666...., but this is integer division, so you will lose your decimals, so hest = 1. Use

`hest = (100.0 / 60.0)`

Same with

`time = minutes * (100/60);`

Changed to

`time = minutes * (100.0 / 60.0);`

In this case again, you will lose your decimals because `time` is an int.

Some would recommend, if speed is an issue, that you perform all [integer calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double) and do store all your items as ints in 1/100th's of a second (i.e. 60 minutes in 1/100ths of a second = 60 minutes*60 seconds*100)

EDIT: Just to clarify, the link is for C++, but the same principles apply. But on most x86 based systems this isn't as big of a deal as it is on power limited embedded systems. Here's [another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550281/floating-point-vs-integer-calculations-on-modern-hardware) that discusses this issue

Answer (score 1):

Following statement is a NOP

```
time = minutes * (100/60);
```

`(100 / 60) == 1` because 100 and 60 are integers. You must write this :

```
time = (minutes * 100) / 60;
```

For instance if `minutes == 123` time will be calculated as `(123 * 100) / 60` which is `12300 / 60` which is `205`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you are mixing floating point and integer arithmetic.  When you divide two integers, your result is integer, but you are trying to print that result as float.  You might consider using the modulus operator (%) and compute quotient and remainder,

```
int // you might want to return float, since you are comingling int and float for time
diff (int start, int slut)
{
    /* slut means end in danish. not using rude words, but I am danish */
    int minutes = 0, seconds = 0, diff;
    int time = 0;
    double hest = (100.0) / (60.0); //here
    printf("hest = %f", hest);
    if(timeVals[start] > timeVals[slut])
    {
        diff = timeVals[start] - timeVals[slut];
        time = diff * (100.0/60.0);
        minutes = diff/60;
        seconds = diff%60; //modulus (remainder after division by 60
    }
    else
    {
        diff = timeVals[slut] - timeVals[start];
        time = time + diff * (100.0/60.0);
        minutes = diff/60;
        seconds = diff%60; //modulus (remainder after division by 60
    }
        /* printing hest to see what the value is */
        printf("t = %f",hest);
        printf("minut:seconds %d:%02d\n", minutes, seconds );
        printf("minut diff: %d\n", time);

    return time;
}
```