# Comparing sqrt(n) with the rational p/q

Tags: performance, math, floating-point

You are given an integer *n* and a rational *p/q* (*p* and *q* are integers).

How do you compare *sqrt(n)* and *p/q*?

**Solution 1**: `sqrt(n) <= (double) p / q`
Should work, but calls `sqrt` which is slower than just using multiplication/division.

**Solution 2:** `(double) n * q * q <= p * p`
Better, but I can't help thinking that because we are using floats, we might get an incorrect answer if *p/q* is very close to *sqrt(n)*. Moreover, it requires converting integers to floats, which is (marginally) slower than just working with integers.

**Solution 3**: `n*q*q <= p*p`
Even better, but one runs into trouble if *p* and *q* get big because of overflow (typically, if *p* or *q* >= 2^32 when working with 64 bits integers).

**Solution 4**: Use solution 3 with a bignum library / in a programming language that has unbound integers.

**Solution 5:** `(q / p) * n <= p / q`
Successfully avoids any overflow problems, but I am not sure that this is correct in all cases, because of integer division...

So... I would happily go with solution 2 or 4, but I was wondering if anyone has clever tricks to solve this problem or maybe a proof (or counter example) that solution 5 works (or not).

Comment: Floating-point is not necessarily slower than integer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550281/floating-point-vs-integer-calculations-on-modern-hardware

Comment: Counter-example to 5: `n = 4; p = 2; q = 1;` Expected outcome: `sqrt(n) == p/q;` Actual outcome: `(1 / 2) * 4` with integer division is `4`, while `2/1` is `2`, yielding `4 <= 2` which is false.

Comment: What is the criteria by which you reckon one solution is *better* than another ?  Or what are the criteria ?  And are you, as your question hints, concerned only with integers representable in 32 or 64 bits ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Criteria would be efficiency and elegance. Concerning the integers: the problem only really arises with 64 bits in my settings. If I have integers of 32 bits or less, I can use 64 bits to do my computations and I do not have overflow problems. If I have integers of more than 64 bits, again overflows would not be a problem (since I would be using a bignum library). But the problem could still be translated to any size: when your inputs have _n_ bits, but you cannot use more than _2*n-1_ bits for your computations.

Comment: Without prior knowledge of a bound on n,p,q, the answer is 4, use bignum

Answer (score 3):

As I commented, a simple and elegant solution is to use bignum, especially if builtin, or easily available in the chosen language. It will work without restriction on n,p,q.

I will develop here an alternate solution based on IEEE floating point when:

- n,p,q are all representable exactly with the given floating point precision (e.g. are within 24 or 53 bits for single or double IEEE 754)
- a fused multiply add is available.

I will note `f` the float type, and `f(x)` the conversion of value x to `f`, presumably rounded to nearest floating point, tie to even.

`fsqrt(x)` will denote the floating point approximation of exact square root.

let `f x = fsqrt(f(n))` and `f y = f(p) / f(q)`.

By IEEE 754 property, both x and y are nearest floating point to exact result, and `n=f(n)`, `p=f(p)`, `q=f(q)` from our preliminary conditions.

Thus if `x < y` then problem is solved `sqrt(n) < p/q`.

And if `x > y` then problem is solved too `sqrt(n) > p/q`.

Else if `x == y` we can't tell immediately...

Let's note the residues `f r = fma(x,x,-n)` and `f s = fma(y,q,-p)`.

We have `r = x*x - n` and `s = y*q - p` exactly. Thus `s/q = y - p/q` (the exact operations, not the floating point ones).

Now we can compare the residual errors. `(p/q)^2 = y^2-2*y*s/q+ (s/q)^2`. How does it compare to `n = x^2 - r`?

`n-(p/q)^2 = 2*y*s/q - r - (s/q)^2`.

We thus have an approximation of the difference `d`, at 1st order: `f d = 2*y*s/f(q) - r`. So here is a C like prototype:

```
int sqrt_compare(i n,i p,i q)
/* answer -1 if sqrt(n)<p/q, 0 if sqrt(n)==p/q, +1 if sqrt(n)>p/q */
/* n,p,q are presumed representable in f exactly */
{
  f x=sqrt((f) n);
  f y=(f) p / (f) q;
  if(x<y) return -1;
  if(x>y) return +1;
  f r=fma(x,x,-(f) n);
  f s=fma(y,(f) q,-(f) p);
  f d=y*s/(f) q - r;
  if(d<0) return -1;
  if(d>0) return +1;
  if(r==0 && s==0) return 0; /* both exact and equal */
  return -1; /* due to 2nd order */
}
```

As you can see, it's relatively short, should be efficient, but is hard to decipher, so at least from this POV, I would not qualify this solution as better than trivial bignum.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider solution 3 with integers 2x the size,

```
n * uint2n_t{q} * q <= uint2n_t{p} * p
```

This overflows if `n * q * q` overflows, but in that case you return false anyway.

```
uint2n_t nqq;
bool overflow = __builtin_mul_overflow(uint2n_t{n} * q, q, &nqq);
(!overflow) && (uint2n_t{n} * q * q <= uint2n_t{p} * p);
```