# Using float type for intermediate variable makes program run slower than int type, why?

Tags: c++, optimization, floating-point, arm, x86-64

I'm currently writing a program for YUV420SP => RGB/BGR color space conversion, follow the floatint-point formula calculation, without any SIMD or multi-threading optimization.

The function's input data is unsigned char type, the finally result's type is also unsigned char type. But for the intermediate variables, the formula itself requires float type(the expressions in the right of the `=`), but for the float => unsigned char conversion, there are **two choices, one is using `float r, g, b` the other is `int r, g, b`**:

```
unsigned char y = 223; // mock for getting y value
unsigned char u = 200; // mock for getting u value
unsigned char v = 200; // mock for getting v value
unsigned char* rgb0 = (unsigned char*)malloc(MAXN); // for finally result saving

// the YUV=>RGB color conversion
float r, g, b; // [!! choice1 !!] if using this line, code run slower
int r, g, b;   // [!! choice2 !!] if using this line, code run much faster
y = std::max(16, (int)y_ptr0[0]);
r = 1.164 * (y - 16) + 1.596 * (v - 128);
g = 1.164 * (y - 16) - 0.813 * (v - 128) - 0.391 * (u - 128);
b = 1.164 * (y - 16) + 2.018 * (u - 128);
rgb0[2-b_idx] = saturate_ucast(r);
rgb0[1] = saturate_ucast(g);
rgb0[b_idx] = saturate_ucast(b);
rgb0 += 3;
```

What makes me confusing is, for the actual test (convert a width=7680x4320 image), **the `float r,g,b` is about much slower that using `int r, g, b`, on both Linux x86 and Android ARMv8 platform**

The full code for the color conversion is:

```cpp
#include <limits.h>
inline uchar saturate_uchar(int v) 
{
    return (uchar)((unsigned int)v <= UCHAR_MAX ? v : v > 0 ? UCHAR_MAX : 0);
}

inline uchar saturate_uchar(float v) 
{
    int iv = round(v);
    return saturate_uchar(iv);
}

template<int u_idx, int b_idx>
void yuv420sp2rgb_naive(
    const uchar* y_plane, int height, int width, int y_linebytes,
    const uchar* uv_plane, int uv_linebytes,
    uchar* rgb, int rgb_linebytes,
    const Option& opt
)
{
    /// param checking
    assert (y_plane!=NULL && uv_plane!=NULL && rgb!=NULL);
    
    /// neon-specific param checking
    assert (width>=2 && height>=2);

    int w = width;
    int h = height;

    for (int i=0; i <= h-2; i+=2)
    {
        const unsigned char* y_ptr0 = y_plane + i * y_linebytes;
        const unsigned char* y_ptr1 = y_ptr0 + y_linebytes;

        unsigned char* rgb0 = rgb + i * rgb_linebytes;
        unsigned char* rgb1 = rgb0+ rgb_linebytes;

        const unsigned char* uv_ptr = uv_plane + (i/2) * uv_linebytes;

        for (size_t j=0; j <= width-2; j += 2)
        {
            int y;
            float r, g, b; // choice1
            //int r, g, b; // choice2

            // R = 1.164(Y - 16) + 1.596(V - 128)
            // G = 1.164(Y - 16) - 0.813(V - 128) - 0.391(U - 128)
            // B = 1.164(Y - 16)                  + 2.018(U - 128)

            int u = uv_ptr[u_idx];
            int v = uv_ptr[1 - u_idx];

            // y00
            y = std::max(16, (int)y_ptr0[0]);
            r = 1.164 * (y - 16) + 1.596 * (v - 128);
            g = 1.164 * (y - 16) - 0.813 * (v - 128) - 0.391 * (u - 128);
            b = 1.164 * (y - 16) + 2.018 * (u - 128);
            rgb0[2-b_idx] = saturate_uchar(r);
            rgb0[1] = saturate_uchar(g);
            rgb0[b_idx] = saturate_uchar(b);
            rgb0 += 3;

            // y01
            y = std::max(16, (int)y_ptr0[1]);
            r = 1.164 * (y - 16) + 1.596 * (v - 128);
            g = 1.164 * (y - 16) - 0.813 * (v - 128) - 0.391 * (u - 128);
            b = 1.164 * (y - 16) + 2.018 * (u - 128);
            rgb0[2-b_idx] = saturate_uchar(r);
            rgb0[1] = saturate_uchar(g);
            rgb0[b_idx] = saturate_uchar(b);
            rgb0 += 3;

            // y10
            y = std::max(16, (int)y_ptr1[0]);
            r = 1.164 * (y - 16) + 1.596 * (v - 128);
            g = 1.164 * (y - 16) - 0.813 * (v - 128) - 0.391 * (u - 128);
            b = 1.164 * (y - 16) + 2.018 * (u - 128);
            rgb1[2-b_idx] = saturate_uchar(r);
            rgb1[1] = saturate_uchar(g);
            rgb1[b_idx] = saturate_uchar(b);
            rgb1 += 3;

            // y11
            y = std::max(16, (int)y_ptr1[1]);
            r = 1.164 * (y - 16) + 1.596 * (v - 128);
            g = 1.164 * (y - 16) - 0.813 * (v - 128) - 0.391 * (u - 128);
            b = 1.164 * (y - 16) + 2.018 * (u - 128);
            rgb1[2-b_idx] = saturate_uchar(r);
            rgb1[1] = saturate_uchar(g);
            rgb1[b_idx] = saturate_uchar(b);
            rgb1 += 3;

            y_ptr0 += 2;
            y_ptr1 += 2;
            uv_ptr += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

| platform | choice | time cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| linux x64 | float r, g, b | 140 ms |
| linux x64 | int r, g, b | 107 ms |
| armv8 | float r, g, b | 152 ms |
| armv8 | int r, g, b | 111 ms |

Question: why changing variable `r,g,b`'s type from `float` to `int` boost speed so much?

Comment: Processors in general are faster at `int` operations than they are at `float` operations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Floating point vs integer calculations on modern hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550281/floating-point-vs-integer-calculations-on-modern-hardware)

Comment: In general, different operations can take different amounts of time; if the difference is important to your application, you'll have to either consult the documentation for the particular device, or measure on your particular hardware and workload (or both)

Comment: BTW, also try `short` or `double` for further comparison..

Comment: Given your numbers, I would say that the difference between int and float is small (~25%). I would be happy if my computer would slowdown less than 25% when the CPU get hot...

Comment: `saturate_uchar(float v)` does more work than the `int` version. Try replacing its body with one that does the same as `saturate_uchar(int v)` (and without calling `round`).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm You are right. I change `int iv = round(v)` to `int iv = v` then time cost decrease from 152ms to 127ms on armv8.

Comment: Have you considered doing the computations entirely as integers instead of floats? `r = 1164 * (y - 16) + 1596 * (v - 128);` and then `saturate_uchar` becomes `return std::clamp((v + 500) / 1000, 0, 255);`

Comment: @RaymondChen Using integer is OK and I knew I can use it. I was wondering each modification would increase/decrease how many seconds, instead of just get the fastest implementation. This seems like what people call it "ablation studies".