# Problem measuring N times the execution time of a code block

Tags: c, time, clock, performance

**EDIT:** I just found my problem after writing this long post explaining every little detail... If someone can give me a good answer on what I'm doing wrong and how can I get the execution time in seconds (using a float with 5 decimal places or so), I'll mark that as accepted. Hint: The problem was on how I interpreted the clock_getttime() man page.

Hi,

Let's say I have a function named `myOperation` that I need to measure the execution time of. To measure it, I'm using `clock_gettime()` as it was recommend [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814569/calculating-cpu-frequency-in-c-with-rdtsc-always-returns-0) in one of the comments.

My teacher recommends us to measure it `N` times so we can get an average, standard deviation and median for the final report. He also recommends us to execute `myOperation` `M` times instead of just one. If `myOperation` is a very fast operation, measuring it `M` times allow us to get a sense of the "real time" it takes; cause the clock being used might not have the required precision to measure such operation. So, execution `myOperation` only one time or `M` times really depends if the operation itself takes long enough for the clock precision we are using.

I'm having trouble dealing with that `M` times execution. Increasing `M` decreases (a lot) the final average value. Which doesn't make sense to me. It's like this, on average you take 3 to 5 seconds to travel from point A to B. But then you go from A to B and back to A 5 times (which makes it 10 times, cause A to B is the same as B to A) and you measure that. Than you divide by 10, the average you get is supposed to be the same average you take traveling from point A to B, which is 3 to 5 seconds.

This is what I want my code to do, but it's not working. If I keep increasing the number of times I go from A to B and back A, the average will be lower and lower each time, it makes no sense to me.

Enough theory, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MEASUREMENTS 1
#define OPERATIONS   1

typedef struct timespec TimeClock;

TimeClock diffTimeClock(TimeClock start, TimeClock end) {
    TimeClock aux;

    if((end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) < 0) {
        aux.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec - 1;
        aux.tv_nsec = 1E9 + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    } else {
        aux.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
        aux.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    }

    return aux;
}

int main(void) {
    TimeClock sTime, eTime, dTime;
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < MEASUREMENTS; i++) {
        printf(" » MEASURE %02d\n", i+1);

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sTime);

        for(j = 0; j < OPERATIONS; j++) {
            myOperation();
        }

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &eTime);

        dTime = diffTimeClock(sTime, eTime);

        printf("   - NSEC (TOTAL): %ld\n", dTime.tv_nsec);
        printf("   - NSEC (OP): %ld\n\n", dTime.tv_nsec / OPERATIONS);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Notes:** The above `diffTimeClock` function is from this [blog post](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/). I replaced my real operation with `myOperation()` because it doesn't make any sense to post my real functions as I would have to post long blocks of code, you can easily code a `myOperation()` with whatever you like to compile the code if you wish.

As you can see, `OPERATIONS = 1` and the results are:

```
 » MEASURE 01
   - NSEC (TOTAL): 27456580
   - NSEC (OP): 27456580
```

For `OPERATIONS = 100` the results are:

```
 » MEASURE 01
   - NSEC (TOTAL): 218929736
   - NSEC (OP): 2189297
```

For `OPERATIONS = 1000` the results are:

```
 » MEASURE 01
   - NSEC (TOTAL): 862834890
   - NSEC (OP): 862834
```

For `OPERATIONS = 10000` the results are:

```
 » MEASURE 01
   - NSEC (TOTAL): 574133641
   - NSEC (OP): 57413
```

Now, I'm not a math wiz, far from it actually, but this doesn't make any sense to me whatsoever. I've already talked about this with a friend that's on this project with me and he also can't understand the differences. I don't understand why the value is getting lower and lower when I increase `OPERATIONS`. The operation itself should take the same time (on average of course, not the exact same time), no matter how many times I execute it.

You could tell me that that actually depends on the operation itself, the data being read and that some data could already be in the cache and bla bla, but I don't think that's the problem. In my case, `myOperation` is reading 5000 lines of text from an CSV file, separating the values by `;` and inserting those values into a data structure. For each iteration, I'm destroying the data structure and initializing it again.

Now that I think of it, I also that think that there's a problem measuring time with `clock_gettime()`, maybe I'm not using it right. I mean, look at the last example, where `OPERATIONS = 10000`. The total time it took was 574133641ns, which would be roughly 0,5s; that's impossible, it took a couple of minutes as I couldn't stand looking at the screen waiting and went to eat something.

Comment: Since you are measuring the wallclock time between two events, you should be using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` rather than `CLOCK_REALTIME` - the latter can jump if the system time is changed, the former is unaffected.

Comment: Yes, but why would the system time change without having me actually do it manually?

Comment: Because a system daemon like `ntpd` changed it? (Or the system administrator on a shared system?)

Comment: Ok, that is unlikely to happen on my test machine. But you have your point. I just used REALTIME instead of MONOTONIC because I've read that some machines (even some Linux distros) don't have MONOTONIC implemented and I want my teacher to able to compile the code (in case his doesn't). Of course, if it's a Mac `clock_gettime()` doesn't even exist (not on my friend's Mac anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your `diffTimeClock()` function to return the number of seconds difference, as a `double`:

```
double diffTimeClock(TimeClock start, TimeClock end) {
    double diff;

    diff = (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1E9;
    diff += (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);

    return diff;
}
```

and in the main routine change `dTime` to a `double`, and the printfs to suit:

```
printf("   - SEC (TOTAL): %f\n", dTime);
printf("   - SEC (OP): %f\n\n", dTime / OPERATIONS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the TimeClock type has two fields, one for seconds and one for nanoseconds. It doesn't make sense to just divide the nanosec field with the number of operations. You need to divide the total time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a POSIX system where there is gettimeofday() function you can use something like this to get the current time in microseconds:

```
long long timeInMicroseconds(void) {
    struct timeval tv;

    gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
    return (((long long)tv.tv_sec)*1000000)+tv.tv_usec;
}
```

The reason why this is very handy is that in order to compute how much your function took you need to do just this:

```
long long start = timeInMicroseconds();
... do your task N times ...
printf("Total microseconds: %lld", timeInMicroseconds()-start);
```

So you don't have to deal with two integers, one with seconds and one with microseconds. Adding and subtracting times will work in a obvious way.

Comment: I don't know if you realized but you did just what you said I wouldn't have to, "to deal with two integers". Look at `return (((long long)tv.tv_sec)*1000000)+tv.tv_usec;`. I did a similar thing to fix my original problem and I have nano precision instead of micro.

Comment: Yes what I meant was, don't deal with two integers explicitly when you need to subtract one time to another time, otherwise it gets harder to check for overflow of nanoseconds (and then subtract 1 second and add 1000000 nanoseconds to the original result).

Instead in the way you did it, and I suggested it, you deal with the two integers only in the function creating the time in microseconds. All the rest of the code will just use the trivial single-number.

Comment: I'm doing that already in the `diffTimeClock()` already, so I don't really understand your post...

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the time() function for this. It shows wall clock time, but that's really what I care about in the end.

One gotcha with performance testing is the operating system may cache file system related operations. So the second (and later) runs can be much faster than the first run. You generally need to test may operations and average the result to get a good feel for the results of any changes you make. There are so many variables this can help you filter out the noise.