# Measuring the CPU frequency scaling effect

Tags: c++, c, cpu, performance-testing

Recently I am trying to measure the effect of the cpu scaling. Is it accurate if I use this clock to measure it?

```
    template<std::intmax_t clock_freq>
    struct rdtsc_clock {
        typedef unsigned long long rep;
        typedef std::ratio<1, clock_freq> period;
        typedef std::chrono::duration<rep, period> duration;
        typedef std::chrono::time_point<rdtsc_clock> time_point;
        static const bool is_steady = true;

        static time_point now() noexcept
        {

            unsigned lo, hi;
            asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi));

            return time_point(duration(static_cast<rep>(hi) << 32 | lo));
        }
    };
```

**Update**:

According to the comment from my another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719617/comparing-the-time-measured-results-produced-by-rdtsc-clock-and-c11-stdchron/19719739?noredirect=1#comment29296515_19719739), I believe redtsc cannot use for measure the effect of cpu frequency scaling because the counter from the redtsc does not affected by the CPU frequency, am i right?

Comment: How closely do your results match the theoretical results?

Comment: enough to present the effect, and their difference

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509727/how-to-detect-if-rdtsc-returns-a-constant-rate-counter-value for information on how to see if your RDTSC supports a constant rate clock, independent of power-saving slow down etc..

Comment: @TonyD Thanks again Tony. yap, i find constant_tsc tagged in the cpuinfo

Comment: @TonyD would you like to draw a conclusion, so i can mark as answer?

Comment: @BryanFok: bit busy - sorry - but you can answer your own question....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need some help in getting the CPU Frequency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774118/need-some-help-in-getting-the-cpu-frequency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment in my another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719617/comparing-the-time-measured-results-produced-by-rdtsc-clock-and-c11-stdchron/19719739?noredirect=1#comment29296515_19719739), in short, redtsc cannot use for measure the effect of cpu frequency scaling because the counter from the redtsc does not affected by the CPU frequency.