# Where can I find a minimalistic WDM driver template with source code in it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, driver, wdk, wdm

I came across kernel-mode drivers with very little experience. Here's what I am trying to do:

- Have a user-mode application that loads the driver.
- Have the user-mode application write to it, in order to send it an instruction.
- Have the driver send the RDMSR instruction to the Intel chip.
- Return the results back to the user-mode application.

I've read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9504/Driver-Development-Part-Introduction-to-Drivers) that describes the different ways in which you can accomplish this behavior (Buffered I/O, Direct I/O, or Neither).

My problem is this...the article has code that represents the way you would structure a WDM driver, and I was expecting to be able to create and then modify a default WDM project template with source code in it using the Windows Driver Kit, but when I downloaded the Windows Driver Kit (WDK), the only WDM driver template was completely blank and did not have any source code.

Where can I find an example of a minimalistic WDM driver template with source code in it that uses [IoCreateDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a device object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/IOCTL-a583bbeb). Part of the [Windows Driver Kit 8.1 Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-8-Driver-Samples-5e1aa62e), the glorious IOCTL driver sample

> demonstrates the usage of four different types of IOCTLs
>   (METHOD_IN_DIRECT, METHOD_OUT_DIRECT, METHOD_NEITHER, and
>   METHOD_BUFFERED)

Furthermore,

> This sample driver is not a Plug and Play driver. This is a minimal
>   driver meant to demonstrate a feature of the operating system. Neither
>   this driver nor its sample programs are intended for use in a
>   production environment. Instead, they are intended for educational
>   purposes and as a skeleton driver.