# Matrix multiplication poor efficiency on a 4 socket NUMA system

Tags: multithreading, openmp, matrix-multiplication, numa

I am developing dense matrix multiplication code (https://github.com/zboson/gemm) to learn about parallel programming. I use OpenMP for the threading. My system has four sockets each with Xeon E5-1620 processor. Each processor has 10 cores/20 hyper-threads. So the total is 40 cores/80 hyper threads.  When I run my code on a single thread I get about 70% of the peak flops (13 out of 19.2 GFLOPS).  However, when I run my code using 40 threads I only get about 30% of the peak flops  (185 out of 682.56 GFLOPS). On a seperate system (Sandy Bridge) with only one socket and 4 cores I get about a 65% efficiency with four threads.

I bind the threads to each physical core [using system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862488/thread-affinity-with-windows-msvc-and-openmp). I have tried disabling this and using instead `export OMP_PROC_BIND=true` or `export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 1 5 9 13 17 21 25 29 33 37 2 6 10 14 18 22 26 30 34 38 3 7 11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39"` but these makes no difference. I still get about 30% efficiency (though I can get worse efficiency with other bad binding settings).

**What more can I do to improve my efficiency?** I understand a [first touch policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850155/openmp-for-schedule) is used so the memory pages are allocated by the first thread that touches them. When I write out the matrix product maybe I should make a separate output for each socket and then merge the results from each socket in the end?

I'm using GCC 4.8.0 with Linux 64-bit kernel 2.6.32

Edit: I use the following binding for matrix size = 2048x2048

```
export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 1 5 9 13 17 21 25 29 33 37 2 6 10 14 18 22 26 30 34 38 3 7 11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39"
```

This should have threads 0-9 -> node 0, 10-19 node 1, 20-29 node 2, 30-39 node 3.

With this binding I get:

```
 nthread    efficiency    node
 1          77%           0
 2          76%           0
 4          74%           0
 6          62%           0
 8          64%           0
10          52%           0
14          50%           0+1
16          30%           0+1
```

Comment: beside nthread, it would be useful to see how it maps on NUMA nodes, e.g. nthreads_node1, nthreads_node2

Comment: @Anton, with the binding I chose t should be threads 0-9 -> node 0, 10-19 node 1, 20-29 node 2, 30-39 node 3

Comment: @Anton, actually, it's not so stable the efficiency is 60 with 16 threads for a while then drops to 30% sometimes. n=2048 seems to be to small.

Comment: it also would be useful to see how efficiency depends on distribution across nodes. e.g. your '16' is likely 10:node1 + 6:node2, what's about 8:node1 + 8:node2? or 4:node1+4:node2+4:node3+4:node4
You probably also need to improve stability of your benchmark - warm up the threads to exclude initialization from measurement, and probably run more iterations of the multiplication (but cache-locality can help for the repeated runs, which can be false-positive  depending on your needs)

Comment: Okay, let me do some tests. This would be a lot easier if I was using ICC and KMP_AFFINITY instead of GCC. I could write my own version. Maybe I should do that. Thank you for helping me BTW.

Comment: BTW, I run the matrix multiplication in a loop and repeatedly print out the efficiency. For threads=16 I do see the efficiency start low at 30% or so and then after several iterations it ramps up to 60%, then sometimes drops below 40% for a few iterations and then ramps back up to 60%.

Comment: @Anton, I just tried 8:node1 + 8:node2. It starts at 30% and after more than 20 iterations goes to 60% and holds there.

Answer (score 2):

It is reasonable to suspect that the efficiency drop also because of too many cross-socket communications. But setting thread affinity is not enough to avoid these communications, it should be addressed on the algorithmic level, e.g. partition the work in the way to minimize cross-numa-node interactions. The best approach is to implement it in a [cache-oblivious way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm), e.g. parallel it not by rows or columns but by 2d tiles.

For example, you can use [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb)::`parallel_for` with `blocked_range2d` in order to use cache more efficiently.

Dropped efficiency with bigger level of parallelism can also indicate that there are not enough work to justify overheads from synchronization.

Comment: Do you have any sources or examples on the "algorithmic level". How should I change my algorithm to work better for NUMA? In terms of not enough work then I should see some improvement with matrix size. By default I test 2048x2048 matrices but I can try larger.

Comment: The efficiency goes to about 40% (as high as 44% sometimes) for 8192x8192 matrices with 40 threads.

Comment: I'm already using 2D tiles https://github.com/zboson/gemm. There is no way I would get 70% efficiency (with one thread) without them. Keep in mind I get 65% with four threads on a non-NUMA system.

Comment: BTW. GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 1 5 9 13 17 21 25 29 33 37 2 6 10 14 18 22 26 30 34 38 3 7 11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39" was an attempt to minimize cross-numa-node interactions. The Linux topology scatters the cpus so thread 0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 correspond to the same node.

Comment: @Zboson, your 65% is for 4 threads, not 40.. huge difference. yo can check whether and how NUMA affects you by running 4 threads, one per socket.

Comment: Good point about checking with 10 threads for one socket. I mean to do that but was not sure how to set the binding.  I get 70% with 4 threads and 50% with 10 thread with n=2048.

Comment: I added a table of efficiency vs. thread number to my question.