# OpenMP thread affinity with GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY and sched_setaffinity

Tags: openmp, affinity

I'm trying to bind OpenMP threads to CPUs. Two methods have been tried.

The first one is `sched_setaffinity`. Every time threads are forked, I invoke `sched_setaffinity` to bind OpenMP threads to CPUs. It seems that binding for every time is far too costly. Is it really needed to bind for every time or just bind for once?

The second one is `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY`. I set `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=0-7` and `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4`. Two nodes are used for computing. Each node has 2 chips and each chip has 4 cores. I place a process in each node and each process forks 4 threads. If `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` is not set, OpenMP does speed up the program. If `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` is set, the following are returned and OpenMP does not work:

```
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 1.
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 2.
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 3.
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 4.
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 5.
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 6.
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 7.
```

Comment: The output looks like as if the OpenMP runtime sees your system as having a single CPU only. What compiler and operating system is that?

Comment: @HristoIliev I actually got this today too, with Intel Fortran 14 and GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-7:2". Strange is I am using this set-up regularly, now just ssh-ing from home there.

Comment: @VladimirF, it could happen if your shell session is somehow limited inside a cgroups container with a very narrow CPU mask. I simply cannot come up with other plausible explanations.

Comment: @Hristolliev OS is linux and kernel release is 2.6.18-164.el5.perfctr. The compiler is gcc 4.6.0.

Comment: @Hristolliev the cluster I use is a little bit old. I have no idea if this can be a problem.

Comment: @matricer, the warning messages as shown are not from the GNU OpenMP runtime library that comes with GCC (libgomp) but from the one that Intel develops. Are you linking into your binary code that was compiled with ICC or using Intel's runtime as a drop-in replacement for libgomp?

Comment: Here is what I use to bind threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862488/thread-affinity-with-windows-msvc-and-openmp

Answer (score -1):

with openmp 4.0, one can set affinity per parallel region

```
#pragma omp parallel proc_bind(close)
```

with nested parallelism, one can also use`proc_bind(spread)` in the outer region to do coarse-grain pining first.

Comment: The OP is using GCC 4.6.0 which supports OpenMP 3.0 only.