# Why is there such a high variability in runtime for adding two values?

Tags: c++, benchmarking, timing

I wrote a timing function that records the run time of a function and calculates the mean and the standard deviation over multiple runs. I was surprised to find very high standard deviations, even for seemingly simple tasks such as adding two doubles.
I analysed the data in python (see the plots). The c++ output was `19.6171 ns +/- 21.9653ns (82799807 runs)` when compiled with:

```
gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-19)
/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++17
```

The whole test was done on my personal computer, which was not idle but running a DE, a browser, my IDE and other processes. There was free RAM available during the test though. My double core CPU with HT was idling below 10% usage.
Is a spike from an average value of 20 ns to 50 µs to be expected for this situation?

**Plot of run times**
This is the content of `std::vector<double> run_times`. I don't see any pattern.
[image: Plot of runtimes over]

**Histogram of run times**
Note log y axis (number of samples in this bin).
[image: Histogram of run times]

**timing.h**

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <ostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <numeric>
#include <fstream>


struct TimingResults{
    // all time results are in nanoseconds
    double mean;
    double standard_deviation;
    uint64_t number_of_runs;
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TimingResults& results);


template <typename InputIterator>
std::pair<typename InputIterator::value_type, typename InputIterator::value_type> 
calculate_mean_and_standard_deviation(InputIterator first, InputIterator last){
    double mean = std::accumulate(first, last, 0.) / std::distance(first, last);
    double sum = 0;
    std::for_each(first, last, [&](double x){sum += (x - mean) * (x - mean);});
    return {mean, std::sqrt(sum / (std::distance(first, last) - 1))};
}


template<uint64_t RunTimeMilliSeconds = 4000, typename F, typename... Args>
TimingResults measure_runtime(F func, Args&&... args){
    std::vector<double> runtimes;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point b;
    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    do {
        auto a = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        b = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        runtimes.push_back(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(b - a).count());
    } while (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(b-start_time).count() <= RunTimeMilliSeconds);
    auto [mean, std_deviation] = calculate_mean_and_standard_deviation(runtimes.begin(), runtimes.end());
    return {mean, std_deviation, runtimes.size()};
}
```

**timing.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "timing.h"


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TimingResults& results){
    return os << results.mean << " ns" << " +/- " << results.standard_deviation << "ns ("
    << results.number_of_runs << " runs)";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "src/timing/timing.h"
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    auto res = measure_runtime([](double x, double y){return x * y;}, 6.9, 9.6);
    std::cout << res;
}
```

Comment: In short, the variation is probably because of your approach of measuring timing and capturing results.  Your loop is doing time checks - including as part of the loop condition - and  pushing values into a vector (which does dynamic memory allocation) on every iteration.    Accesses of a clock to check timing will have jitter unless your code is being executed on a hard real time platform.   Dynamic memory allocation and deallocation (which will happen eventually if enough elements are pushed to a vector) is also non-deterministic on most systems, so the time taken will vary.

Comment: I don't think `vector`'s memory allocations have anything to do with it. They happen outside the measurement interval (given by the two calls to `now()`).

Comment: @Peter: on modern x86, (like the OP's Debian system with an Intel CPU), the timesource for `now()` should be a RDTSC instruction in user-space (with scale factors exported by the kernel via the VDSO page).  There's still quite a lot of instructions that have to run if you single-step into it, but nowhere near as slow as a system call.  I wouldn't really expect jitter in the clock itself, just in the code that accesses it.  The TSC ticks at near the reference frequency (not max turbo) so it does have ~0.25ns precision on a 4GHz CPU. [related](//stackoverflow.com/q/13772567)

Comment: @Peter Yes, I kept only the function between the measuring intervals `a` and `b`. The other timing code just limits the total runtime to 4 seconds.

Comment: And yes @Olaf: spikes are totally expected because of interrupts.  Even "hard realtime" doesn't mean dependable timing down to the clock-cycle.  It just puts a cap on worst-case latency.  50 us still sounds reasonable for most hard-realtime systems.

Comment: @Jonas: a system call to allocate new memory may push this loop and/or the `now()` function out of uop cache and even L1-instruction cache, and maybe the iTLB.  And also (with Spectre mitigation) make branch-prediction cold. 
 Although you'd expect most of the cost to be before the `rdtsc` in the start-the-clock `now()`, i.e. outside the timed interval.

Answer (score 7):

Modern CPUs easily perform on the order of several 10^9 FLOPS, i.e. the expected time for one operation is below 1 ns. This, however refers to peak-performance. For most real-world workloads, the performance is going to be much less, owing to memory and cache effects.

The problem with your benchmark is that **you are timing individual operations**. The overhead of getting the time points `a` and `b` likely simply exceeds the time you are actually trying to measure. Additionally, even `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is not going to give you picosecond accuracy (though that's in principle implementation and hardware depended). The obvious fix is to perform the operation `N` times, time that and then divide the total time by `N`. At some point, you'll see that your results become consistent. (Feel free to post your results.)

TL;DR: You are trying to time a lightning bolt with a pocket watch.

Comment: More importantly, out-of-order execution can overlap one FP add with the timing overhead.  **The `return x*y` result is also never used, so probably optimized away after `func` inlines into the timing loop**, or at least hoisted out of the loop.  We literally can't tell from looking at the timing results!  Also the inputs are compile-time constants, so there's no need to eval it at runtime.

Comment: @PeterCordes Two very good points. Optimizations should probably be turned off to avoid this. (Or look at the assembly to check work is actually being done). Out-of-order execution should be less of an issue once multiple operations are executed in a loop before taking the time.

Comment: No, disabling optimizations would turn this into a microbenchmark of call/ret through a nest of C++ functions, and maybe store-forwarding latency.  Benchmarking with optimizations disabled is useless.  Typically you need to use inline asm to force the compiler to materialize a value in a register repeatedly in a loop, and/or forget what it knows about a variable's value to make it redo a calculation instead of hoisting it.  e.g. see ["Escape" and "Clobber" equivalent in MSVC](//stackoverflow.com/q/33975479) (not the MSVC part, just the part in the question showing useful GNU C inline asm).

Comment: And yes usually you should put stuff in a repeat loop.  You have to choose whether you want to measure throughput or latency (by making the operations dependent on the previous or not).  **Microbenchmarking is *hard***, and for this simple an operation doesn't make any sense at the C++ level, only when you also consider the asm for the specific CPU it will run on.

Answer (score 3):

TL:DR: Your entire approach is too simplistic to tell you anything useful.  Timing overhead would dominate even if your multiply wasn't optimized away.

---

**Microbenchmarking is non-trivial even in hand-written asm.**  It's impossible in C++ if you don't understand how your C++ compiles to asm for your target platform, for an operation as simple / cheap as `x * y`.

You aren't using the result, so maybe you were trying to measure throughput (instead of latency).  But with only one multiply inside the timed interval, there's no chance for superscalar / pipelined execution to happen.

Even more fundamentally, **you don't use the result** so there's no need for the compiler to even compute it at all.  And even if you did, after inlining from that C++ header **the operands are compile-time constants, so the compiler will do it once at compile time** instead of with a `mulsd` instruction at run time.  And even if you made the args in `main` come from `atof(argv[1])` or something, the compiler could hoist the computation out of the loop.

Any *one* of those 3 microbenchmark pitfalls would lead to **timing an empty interval** with no work between the two functions, other than saving the first `now()` result to different registers.  You have all 3 problems.

You're literally timing an empty interval and still getting this much jitter because of the occasional interrupt, and the relatively high overhead of the library function wrapped around `clock_gettime` which ultimately runs an `rdtsc` instruction and scales it using values exported by the kernel.  Fortunately it can do this in user-space, without actually using a `syscall` instruction to enter the kernel.  (The Linux kernel exports code + data in the VDSO pages.)

Directly using `rdtsc` inside a tight loop does give fairly repeatable timings, but still has pretty high overhead relative to `mulsd`.  ([How to get the CPU cycle count in x86_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/how-to-get-the-cpu-cycle-count-in-x86-64-from-c)).

Your mental model of execution cost is probably wrong at this level of detail.  You can't just time individual operations and then add up their costs.  Superscalar pipelined out-of-order execution means you have to consider throughput vs. latency, and lengths of dependency chains.  (And also front-end bottlenecks vs. the throughput of any one kind of instruction, or execution port).

- [Modern x86 cost model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957004/modern-x86-cost-model)
- [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692718/how-many-cpu-cycles-are-needed-for-each-assembly-instruction/44980899#44980899)
- [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607391/what-considerations-go-into-predicting-latency-for-operations-on-modern-supersca)

---

**And no, disabling optimizations is not useful.**  That would turn this into a microbenchmark of call/ret through a nest of C++ functions, and maybe store-forwarding latency.

Benchmarking with optimizations disabled is useless.  Typically you need to use inline asm to force the compiler to materialize a value in a register repeatedly in a loop, and/or forget what it knows about a variable's value to make it redo a calculation instead of hoisting it.  e.g. see ["Escape" and "Clobber" equivalent in MSVC](//stackoverflow.com/q/33975479) (not the MSVC part, just the part in the question showing useful GNU C inline asm).