# Why isn't a constant multiply realized by a mul instruction?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64

Let's consider the following function:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t foo(uint64_t x) { return x * 3; }
```

If I were to write it, I'd do

```
.global foo
.text
foo:
    imul %rax, %rdi, $0x3
    ret
```

On the other hand, the compiler generates two additions, with `-O0`:

```
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
   8:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
   c:   48 89 d0                mov    %rdx,%rax
   f:   48 01 c0                add    %rax,%rax
  12:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
  15:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  16:   c3                      retq
```

or `lea` with `-O2`:

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   48 8d 04 7f             lea    (%rdi,%rdi,2),%rax
   4:   c3                      retq
```

Why? Since every assembly instruction equals one processor clock tick, my version should run within 2 CPU clock cycles (since it has two instructions), in the `-O0` we need 4 cycles for performing addition, because it could be rewritten to

```
  mov    %rdi,%rax
  add    %rax,%rax
  add    %rdi,%rax
  retq
```

and the `lea` should take two cycles either.

Comment: "Since every assembly instruction equals one processor clock tick" this is not true.

Comment: Your title does not reflect the body of your question.

Comment: The title being essentially "*What's the `q` for?*"

Comment: Yes, I gave it the wrong title. Fixed that.

Comment: Often compilers know better than a human what is the fastest way. Sometimes not, but often yes. I remember that on X86, the compiler always  produced the sequence "push bp; mov bp, sp; sub sp,xxx" instead of the single one "enter xxx". It turned out that the compiler was right, those three instructions were faster than a single "enter xxx".

Comment: Relevant: [Why does my assembly use “+” and “*” signs instead of instructions for calculating addresses?](/q/23659656) contains some of the answer.  The mention that the address-arithmetic unit is faster than ALU addition misses another point, namely that arithmetic resources may be used by other threads or by speculative/out-of-order execution if simple code like this leaves them available.  That's really hard to get right without the compiler thinking for you.

Comment: Other somewhat-duplicates: [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980899) / [Assembly why lea is fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67034266)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're targeting a processor with dedicated address-calculation units.  It's likely to be faster to compute small multiplications in the address calculator than in a general-purpose arithmetic/logic unit (ALU).

Also, depending on your processor model, the ALU may be shared with other code, either due to hyperthreading or by speculative or out-of-order execution within the same thread.  Your compiler is making a good estimate of how best to utilise the available resources to give a good throughput of execution without stalling.

The idea that "*every assembly instruction equals one processor clock tick*" (or even a fixed number of cycles) has only ever been true on the very simplest of processors.

Comment: Is there any resource about how many instruction cycles each instruction takes?

Comment: Where does the multiplication happen then?

Comment: With old-school microprocessors such as 8080, it's possible to count cycles, but with superscalar out-of-order processors such as x86-64, it's a lot more difficult, because instructions overlap so much.  Not only that, but instruction and data access times can vary greatly depending on whether the accessed memory is in cache (and which level of cache).

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I expect there's an address calculator unit that's much smaller than the ALU, and can do addition and some shifts (i.e. multiply by 1,2,4,8,16), probably with a restricted set of source operands (perhaps a subset of registers, some immediate or fixed values and not much else).  It's possible for some implementations of the instruction set to turn to main ALU for these operations while more expensive chips have dedicated addressing unit, so you really need to consult your documentation.

Comment: @marmistrz: [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980899) and [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391) have some good info.  You can't simply add up a "cycle cost" for each instruction, the whole point of superscalar out-of-order exec is to do better than that.

Comment: There isn't a single "the ALU", for example Haswell has integer ALUs on four separate execution ports, two of which can run LEA (at 1 cycle latency), 1 of which can run imul (at 3 cycle latency).  https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/4/ / https://uops.info/, especially https://agner.org/optimize/.  Out-of-order exec CPUs generally don't run LEA on an AGU, instead just replicating the shift-and-add logic in an ALU instead of having scheduling competition between loads/stores and instructions that don't access memory.