# Why doesn't the C99 compiler optimize "!a && b" as "a < b" for booleans?

Tags: c, boolean, compiler-optimization, boolean-logic

I saw [this really interesting tweet](https://twitter.com/chordbug/status/1064932667089670144):

> resisting my code golf instinct to turn `if(!bool1 && bool2)` into `if(bool1<bool2)`

I had never seen that before, so I wanted to see if compilers would also use this optimization. I started a repo with a README and a test C program: https://github.com/ndbroadbent/gcc_experiments

Here is the test program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  if(argc != 3) {
    printf("Usage: %s <a> <b>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }
  bool a = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) != 0;
  bool b = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10) != 0;

  if (!a && b) {
    printf("!a && b == true (a: %d, b: %d)\n", a, b);
  } else {
    printf("!a && b == false (a: %d, b: %d)\n", a, b);
  }
}
```

I tried compiling this program with both the `gnu90` and `C99` standards. I know C99 has a `bool` type, but is that still treated like an integer, so the compiler can't make any optimizations based on boolean logic?

I might be reading the assembly wrong, but it looks like C99 with `-O3` is also including `jne` and `je` instructions, instead of just using one "less than" operation and a single jump instruction. It looks like C++ doesn't make this optimization either.

Comment: "I tried compiling this program with both GCC and C99." - What do you mean? GCC is a compiler and C99 is a standard.

Comment: Sorry I just mean I used both `gcc` and `c99` on the command line. So the default for `gcc` is apparently `-std=gnu90`, and calling `/usr/bin/c99` sets `-std=c99`. I updated my question to refer to the standards instead of the command-line tools I was running.

Comment: What is the assembly output then?

Comment: if `bool1` is true, you're comparing to another value when you could just bail out with a single test. I guess it depends on the stats of the outcome of the booleans.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I tried all of the different optimization options (from -O0 to -O3). I have added the output from `objdump` to my GitHub repo: https://github.com/ndbroadbent/gcc_experiments

Comment: Your latest edit modifies the apparent question to be about details of the cost of specific assembly instructions.  I didn't think that was where you were aiming, but if that's where you really want to go, then this question is a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692718/how-many-cpu-cycles-are-needed-for-each-assembly-instruction).

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're right, that wasn't really where I wanted to go. I saw that other question and answers, but they didn't really answer my question.

Comment: @ndbroadbent, at this point, then, I think you're better off accepting an answer and then asking a new question about what you really want to know.  As you're probably aware, changing the question out from under existing answers is not well received around here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hmm, so far none of the answers really explain why this optimization isn't being used. I've just performed some benchmarks and `a < b` is usually a bit faster than `!a && b` for random data.

Comment: I think @n.m.'s answer is actually pretty clear on that: the optimization is not performed because the compiler thinks the version it does emit is better.  Whether it turns out to be right about that is likely to be context and hardware dependent.

Comment: Ok good point, I will accept that answer then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compilers are well aware of the eqivalence and are able to optimise based on it. Their idea of what should be optimised to what might be [opposite from yours](https://godbolt.org/z/nDrBiD) though.

For sake of completeness, here's the clang-produced assembly output of a function that does `!a && b` and also of a function that does “a < b”. It's the same assembly output in both cases.

```
    mov     eax, edi
    not     al
    and     al, sil
    ret
```

Comment: Haha awesome, that was a great way to show that the compiler knows they are equivalent. Thanks!

Comment: I should also point out that GCC 8.2 doesn't make this optimization, but clang/llvm seems to be smarter and knows that they are equivalent.

Comment: Linking to an off-site resource without explaining it in the answer is not good for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Really interesting that it still uses the `jne` and `je` instructions for my original code, even if I change it to `a < b`: https://godbolt.org/z/bUfgEd
On my CPU that's actually a little bit slower than the single `cmp` instruction.

Comment: that answer could include the snippets directly as well. Else it's link only even if it's good