# Why is a switch not optimized the same way as chained if else in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

The following implementation of square produces a series of cmp/je statements like I would expect of a chained if statement:

```c
int square(int num) {
    if (num == 0){
        return 0;
    } else if (num == 1){
        return 1;
    } else if (num == 2){
        return 4;
    } else if (num == 3){
        return 9;
    } else if (num == 4){
        return 16;
    } else if (num == 5){
        return 25;
    } else if (num == 6){
        return 36;
    } else if (num == 7){
        return 49;
    } else {
        return num * num;
    }
}
```

And the following produces a data table for return:

```c
int square_2(int num) {
    switch (num){
        case 0: return 0;
        case 1: return 1;
        case 2: return 4;
        case 3: return 9;
        case 4: return 16;
        case 5: return 25;
        case 6: return 36;
        case 7: return 49;
        default: return num * num;
    }
}
```

Why is gcc unable to optimize the top one into the bottom one?

Dissassembly for reference: https://godbolt.org/z/UP_igi

EDIT: interestingly, MSVC generates a jump table instead of a data table for the switch case. And surprisingly, clang optimizes them to the same result.

Comment: I would say `switch` has dedicated generation code (even before optimization)...

Comment: What do you mean "undefined behavior"? As long as the observable behavior is the same, the compiler can generate whatever assembly/machine code it wants

Comment: @super, [uhmmmm](https://godbolt.org/z/q-pLFg) clang does optimize it into the exact same assembler.

Comment: The semantics are not the same so the optimization you describe is impossible. The `if/else` chain gives a specific order of execution; `switch` does not. NB Your title is back to front.

Comment: @user207421 ignoring the `return`s; the cases have no `breaks`, thus the switch also has a specific order of execution. The if/else chain has returns in every branch, the semantics in this case are equivalent. The optimization is not [impossible](https://godbolt.org/z/bQA7DW). As a counterexample [icc](https://godbolt.org/z/ZpHppx) does not optimize any of the functions.

Comment: Maybe the simplest answer... gcc is just not able to see this structure and optimize it (yet).

Comment: I agree with @user1810087 . You simply found the current boundary of the compiler refinement process. A sub-sub-case that is not currently recognized as optimizable (by some compilers). In fact, not every else-if chain can be optimized that way, but only the subset in which the SAME variable is tested against constant values.

Comment: The if-else has a different execution order, from top to bottom. Still, replacing the code with just if statements didn't improve the machine code. The switch on the other hand, has no pre-defined execution order and is essentially just a glorified goto jump table. That being said, a compiler is allowed to reason about the observable behavior here, so the poor optimization of the if-else version is quite disappointing.

Comment: `switch` is locked into comparing `num` whereas the `if(){}else if(){}` can compare whatever TF it wants at any time.

Comment: Multiplication is more efficient than all this `if...else` and `switch...case` trickery anyway.

Comment: The issue has been reported to GCC 15+ years ago https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14799, and couple of months ago Martin Liška said he is working on it.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in GCC 12.x and up apparently

Answer (score 30):

The generated code for `switch-case` conventionally uses a jump table. In this case, the direct return through a look-up table seems to be an optimization making use of the fact that every case here involves a return. Though the standard makes no guarantees to that effect, I would be surprised if a compiler were to generate a series of compares instead of a jump-table for a conventional switch-case.

Now coming to `if-else`, it is the exact opposite. While `switch-case` executes in constant time, irrespective of the number of branches, `if-else` is optimized for a smaller number of branches. Here, you would expect the compiler to basically generate a series of comparisons in the order that you have written them.

So if I had used `if-else` because I expect most calls to `square()` to be for `0` or `1` and rarely for other values, then 'optimizing' this to a table-lookup could actually cause my code to run slower than I expect, defeating my purpose for using an `if` instead of a `switch`. So although it is debatable, I feel GCC is doing the right thing and clang is being overly aggressive in its optimization.

Someone had, in the comments, shared a link where clang does [this optimization](https://godbolt.org/z/bQA7DW) and generates lookup-table based code for `if-else` as well. Something notable happens when we reduce the number of cases to just two (and a default) with clang. It once again generates identical code for both if and switch, but this time,
[switches over to compares and moves](https://godbolt.org/z/xD_HNg) instead of the lookup-table approach, for both. This means that even the switch-favoring clang knows that the 'if' pattern is more optimal when the number of cases is small!

In summary, a sequence of compares for `if-else` and a jump-table for `switch-case` is the standard pattern that compilers tend to follow and developers tend to expect when they write code. However, for certain special cases, some compilers might choose to break this pattern where they feel it provides better optimization. Other compilers might just choose to stick to the pattern anyway, even if apparently sub-optimal, trusting the developer to know what he wants. Both are valid approaches with their own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Yes, optimization is a multi-edged sword: What they write, what they want, what they get, and who we curse for that.

Comment: *"...then 'optimizing' this to a table-lookup would actually cause my code to run slower than I expect..."* Can you provide a justification for this? Why would a jump table ever be slower than *two* possible conditional branches( to check inputs against `0` and `1`)?

Comment: @CodyGray I have to confess that I did not got to the level of counting cycles - I just went by a gut-feeling that the load from memory through a pointer might take more cycles than a compare and jump, but I could be wrong. However, I hope you agree with me that even in this case, at least for '0', `if` is obviously faster? Now, here is an example of a platform where both 0 and 1 would be faster when using `if` than when using switch: https://godbolt.org/z/wcJhvS (Note that there are multiple other optimizations in play here as well)

Comment: Well, counting cycles doesn't work on modern superscalar OOO architectures anyway. :-) Loads from memory are not going to be slower than mispredicted branches, so the question is just how likely is the branch to be predicted? That question applies to all manner of conditional branches, whether generated by explicit `if` statements or automatically by the compiler. I'm not an ARM expert, so I'm not really sure if the claim you're making regarding `switch` being faster than `if` is true. It would depend on the penalty for mispredicted branches, and that would actually depend on *which* ARM.

Answer (score 1):

One possible rationale is that if low values of `num` are more likely, for example always 0, the generated code for the first one might be faster. The generated code for switch takes equal time for all values.

Comparing the best cases, according to [this table](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980899/2527795) for the explanation of the table.

If `num == 0`, for "if" you have xor, test, je (with jump), ret. Latency: 1 + 1 + jump. However, xor and test are independent so the actual execution speed would be faster than 1 + 1 cycles.

If `num < 7`, for "switch" you have mov, cmp, ja (without jump), mov, ret. Latency: 2 + 1 + no jump + 2.

A jump instruction that does not result to jump is faster than one that results to jump. However, the table does not define the latency for a jump, so it is not clear to me which one is better. It is possible that the last one is always better and GCC is simply not able to optimize it.

Comment: Hmm, interesting theory, but for ifs vs switch you have: xor, test, jmp vs mov, cmp jmp. Three instructions each with the last being a jump. Seems equal in the best case, no?

Comment: "A jump instruction that does not result to jump is faster than one that results to jump.". It's the branch prediction which matters.