# Cupy API and elementwise kernel for faster neural network

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, cupy

I know I can easily rewrite numpy dot product in cupy dot product by using corresponding API:

```
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

arr1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
arr2 = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
np.dot(arr1, arr2)

arr1_ = cp.asarray(arr1)
arr2_ = cp.asarray(arr2)
cp.dot(arr1_, arr2_)
```

I [read](https://towardsdatascience.com/make-your-python-functions-10x-faster-142ab40b31a7) that elementwise kernels in cupy run a lot faster (over hundreds times faster than corresponding numpy dot product). So I was guessing **Q1.** if I can do above dot product using elementwise kernel, or its that dot product is simply not an elementwise operation?

I wanted to increase the execution speed of neural network that I coded from scratch in numpy (for academic purpose and I dont want to use pytorch or tensorflow). And most of operations in neural network computation involve dot product. **Q2.** So, if we cannot use cupy elementwise kernel for dot product, then for what else I can use them (in the context of neural networks involving multiclass classification)?

**Q3.** Is there any faster alternative in cupy for `cupy.dot`? (Just want to be sure I am utilising fastest approach)

Comment: `numpy` `dot/matmul` is fast, since it uses `BLAS` code (at least for float dtype arrays).  `dot` is not an element-wise multiplication, `A*B`.  Your link doesn't mention `dot`.  There is a bar in graph for `matrix multiplication`.

Comment: What do you mean by "`numpy` `dot/matmul` is fast"? `numpy.dot` is faster than `cupy.dot`? Does the "matrix multiplication" bar in that graph refer dot product and mean `cupy.dot` is almost 20 times faster than `numpy.dot`?

Comment: A possibly relevant SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68754407/why-are-cuda-gpu-matrix-multiplies-slower-than-numpy-how-is-numpy-so-fast

Comment: @hpaulj super thanks for pointing me to great post!!! It definitely proves `cupy.dot` is way faster than `numpy.dot` on gpu. I feel Q1 and Q3 are somewhat answered: we cannot use elementwise kernel for dot product and `cupy.dot` is very fast and may not have any faster alternative. But I guess Q2 is still remained. Can you please imagine ways where we can you elementwise kernel in the context neural network implementation from scratch?

Comment: In `einsum` terminology, matrix multiplication is 'ij,jk->ik'.  That can be thought of as  'ij1' ' * ' '1jk' producing a 'ijk', followed by a 'j' sum, where the star is a broadcasted elementwise multiplication.  But 'highly optimized BLAS code' takes a more direct approach, with low level iterations on the shared 'j'