# Configure qemu KVM-SVM to not emulate rdtscp and get valid timestamp

Tags: x86-64, qemu, kvm, amd-processor, rdtsc

I am trying to measure the cycle count of an instruction in a VM -- my code looks like this:

```
start = rdtscp();
//complex_sequence_of_instructions
end = rtdscp();
//complex_sequence_of_instructions took end-time cycles
```

To the best of my knowledge, using `rdtscp` in a VM does not provide an accurate cycle count, however. I launch my VM like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu EPYC-v4 [...]
```

on a zen3 AMD CPU (without SEV enabled). Is there any way I can configure kvm to no trap the `rdtscp` instruction and get an accurate timestamp measurement?

Comment: `//Increasing i took end-time cycles` - RDTSC and RDTSCP have significant overhead compared to executing one instruction.  That's not a meaningful microbenchmark even on bare metal.  Also, a single time in cycles isn't very meaningful for something as short as incrementing an integer; you need to measure throughput separately from latency.  See [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/692718)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes -- I should have picked another instruction for illustration. I am actually benchmarking a more complex sequence of instructions -- edited the post