# Good ways to compare 2 assembly files?

Tags: python, assembly, compare, pattern-matching

I’m making a simple tool to analyze differenet compilers’ “smartness” to recognize certain functions/programs as built-in instructions. The stumbling block for me is how to compare the assembly file that a compiler produced with another assembly file being a template of what code was expected? Naive ways such as simply comparing the two files line by line wouldn’t work because such minute changes as register names or extra whitespaces would produce an unpassed test.

I’m writing the tool in Python.

diff, Levenshtein distance

Comment: Try using `difflib`

Comment: I would rather work with object files than generate assembly files. With object files, you can parse them easily (since they are binary files) and read the machine code of the function of interest. Then you can use a library like iced_x86 or capstone to disassemble the machine code into instruction **objects** and compare two lists of these objects as you deem appropriate. That's as far as we can go I guess as there aren't many details in your questions and there is no universal distance function between instructions or sequences thereof.

Answer (score 2):

To factor out register allocation choices, perhaps produce a graph of the data dependencies between instructions, like https://uica.uops.info/ does if you check the "dependencies" checkbox, then click on the "Open Dependencies" link after doing a run to generate results.

Comparing graphs for similarity is probably good because data dependencies between instructions are what out-of-order exec really cares about.  For example, `inc eax` / `inc edx` isn't significantly different from `inc edx` / `inc eax` except on in-order CPUs (e.g. if the previous instruction wrote EDX, then it couldn't pair with `inc edx` on P5, or the equivalent with R0 on ARM Cortex A53 or [A510](https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/10/01/arms-cortex-a510-two-kids-in-a-trench-coat/).).  Different compiler versions / options / tuning settings often produce pretty much the same instructions with the same data dependencies, but with different static scheduling.

(uiCA only really works properly for non-branchy loop bodies, so the general case may get hairier when you have control dependencies as well as data dependencies.)

---

More about data flow graphs, see https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2018/03/05/a-whirlwind-introduction-to-dataflow-graphs/ which BeeOnRope mentioned in [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692718/how-many-cpu-cycles-are-needed-for-each-assembly-instruction/44980899#44980899)  (Because it's the kind of graph tools like uiCA, IACA, and LLVM-MCA need to make to find loop-carried dependency chains to find bottlenecks in loops.)

Comment: This is not something I've tried; I don't know tricky it would end up being to get something useful out of this idea I just had.  But I'm well aware of the problem you're running into that trivial differences can make a text-based `diff` a total mess, or even just symbol names.  Even moreso for diffing `objdump` output where different numeric offsets pollute the diff.